# Android Youtube API crashes when playing videos that support 3D

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using the new YouTube Android API and I have observed that as soon as you load a video that is capable of 3D playback, the API crashes internally.

Now my question is: Can is disable 3D playback or give any parameter to the API to indicate which resolution I want to play? Or disable HD playback, or anything like that?

Goddchen

Comment: Thanks - we've reported it to engineering.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a supported method to disable 3D or change resolution right now.

There was a bug reported about this issue and it got fixed recently.

Please try it again and report the issue to public issue tracker with examples and crash report.

'https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)'